# Convertir escuesta en fichero pdf, en excel con python

Tags: python

estoy buscando informacion de como convertir los resultados de una encuesta, en la cual esta marcada con una x la respuesta, en un archivo excel. Aun no he podido solucionarlo. Alguien prodria ayudarme?
Gracias

Comment: Por favor, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/590361/edit) tu pregunta y proporciona los detalles necesarios para entender lo que buscas. ¿Qué encuesta? ¿Cómo deseas convertirla? ¿Que has intentado? pues no somos adivinos